# How to assign safe-names to own instances like Framework does?

Tags: .net, vb.net, types, naming

When adding a control to the designer, or a new item, or instancing a control at execution time a safe-name is generated by Framework... like: `Textbox1`, `Textbox2`, `Textbox3`, etc...

I would like to reproduce that safe-naming with my own type (which don't inherits from a control but I don't know if that is very important).

This is an example class:

```
NotInheritable Class GlobalHotkey : Inherits NativeWindow : Implements IDisposable

   Public property Name

End Class
```

Then at execution time I would like to do this:

```
dim MyObject as New GlobalHotkey(Parameters)
' Notice that I did not set manually the name property...


Sub something()...

    Msgbox(MyObject.Name)
    ' Desired result: "GlobalHotkey1"

End sub
```

Comment: I don't recall the details, but this is a Designer-level feature. Are you familiar with adding Designer support to custom controls? If not, then I recommend that you _become_ familiar.

Comment: `...or instancing a control at execution time a safe-name is generated by Framework...` how it possible. If you write code `Dim myobject As Control` this is already given name `myobject`. Designer generate a code in .vb file ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your thing (cant tell if it is a class, control or component) inherits from `Component` or implements `IComponent` vb/vs will handle creating a unique name for you and write it to the designer file (provided you have things properly tagged for serialization).

Another option is to use a `TypeConverter` on your class and handle it yourself.

Mainly what either of these does is prevent `FooBar` being added twice to the designer file and then fed to the form in the `InitializeComponent` procedure.  It doesnt have much to do with your runtime example unless you want to serialize `Parameters` to make sure it is unique with only one key handler handling a given key combo.